# Enable --shell-escape in TexMaker

Tags: texmaker, shell-escape

I am trying to use `dot2texi` package with Texmaker on a Mac, and I am aware that I need to enable shell escape in order to let TeX Live process using external packages. So I edit the commands in Texmaker to the following:

```
"/usr/texbin/latex" -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex (for LaTeX)

"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex (for PdfLaTeX)
```

However, when I try outputting the following TeX file, I keep getting warning that says "shell escape not enabled", and consequently the `dot2texi` doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% dot graphs
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\author{Anonymous}
\title{Dot graphs in \LaTeX}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{dot2tex}[dot,options=-tmath --autosize --cache]
digraph G 
{
   node [shape="circle"]; 
   a_1 -> a_2 -> a_3 -> a_4 -> a_1;
}
\end{dot2tex}}

\end{document}
```

Not sure what else I need to do here. Any suggestion would be extremely welcome.

Comment: If I do that, I get that the shell escape is enabled. Check that the called compiler is one of the two.

Comment: Did you try `-shell-escape`? (note that it uses one dash)