# TexMaker hangs when running shell scripts

Tags: texmaker, shell-escape

I have trouble using `\write18` within TexMaker.

I created a 'user command' within TexMaker, which invokes a simple shell script.  But even that has trouble executing.  It just seems to wait forever.

So the problem may not be `\write18` per se, but it has to do with TexMaker making system calls.

What can be done to resolve this?

Here is the Tex file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\immediate\write18{./count-words.sh}

\begin{document}
\input{word-count.txt}
\end{document}
```

And here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
words=$(detex test.tex | wc -m)
calc "int(round(${words}/100.0)*100)" > word-count.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure you have shell escape enabled in TeXmaker? See [Enable --shell-escape in TexMaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44243/), where the correct flag is `-shell-escape` with one leading hyphen.

Comment: I tried, putting it in the latex commands, but the problem is that I can't even execute shell scripts in "user commands".

Comment: I got some very strange behavior... the \write18 is executed, but the call is non-blocking.  So I'd have to compile twice to have the desired effect.

Comment: And I still cannot execute shell scripts in user commands.

Comment: Does it work if you compile from the command line with `-shell-escape`? That will narrow things down to either your script or to TeXmaker. I'm not aware of any restrictions on running shell scripts versus binaries.

Comment: OK, it works perfectly when running from command-line.

Comment: By that I mean calling XeLatex directly.  The `\write18` works and the script executes correctly.  But when this is done within TexMaker's GUI it fails.

Comment: In the GUI, it takes extraordinarily long to run the script, and the "waiting" icon doesn't change.  I have to manually click either the "stop" button or the "view PDF" button to stop the "waiting state".  Then I see that the script actually has executed.  What could possibly be the cause?

Comment: PS:  the script is just a simple one-liner.  And if I put "beep" as the command, it executes instantly.

Comment: Update:  I found the culprit:  it's due to calling the `calc` utility inside my script.  For some unknown reason `calc` causes the execution to hang...

Comment: I used `python -c "print ...."` to do the calculation and it runs fine.

Comment: Not having seen the script, maybe the `calc` version wants a terminal for input or output, and calling it from `-shell-escape` doesn't provide that? Maybe run `calc </dev/null` instead of just `calc`?

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem!  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Since you have it solved now, please write up a small MWE and script that shows the problem and the solution, and you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: What's the `calc` utility?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it wasn't actually about LaTeX, but rather `calc` as used in the OP's bash script.

Comment: It is specific to the GUI of TexMaker, and it might affect other users who use commands similar to `calc` in their scripts.  But I'm not sure if TexMaker itself is on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

The following small change to the script fixes the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
words=$(detex test.tex | wc -m)
calc "int(round(${words}/100.0)*100)" </dev/null > word-count.txt
```

The problem arises if I don't include the `</dev/null`.  It causes `calc` to hang.

Comment: Please add the follow-up information into your question by clicking the `edit` under your question. This space is reserved only for answers.

Comment: That is the answer....

Comment: Read your question and your answer. Do you think they are really connected? What does it have to do with TeXMaker what you write in your script?

Comment: TexMaker calls the script, but the script hangs due to a need for input from the terminal.  I'm talking about the GUI of TexMaker.